# Java Scanner acting oddly

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am encountering a problem I cannot figure out. I am using a single Scanner object and am passing it around (painfully I learned that multiple Scanner objects on the same stream cause issues https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+byte+or+character+stream). The Scanner works fine, and collects information from the user before and after this section of the code. However in this section of the code, it does not stop to get user input.

Can you help explain why the code below is broken?

```
//class A
Scanner in; //global value

String bookName = "";//global value

in = new Scanner(System.in); //initialized in class A constructor

//inside main of class A

System.out.println("before: " + a.bookName);
a.bookName = c.getBookName(a.in, a.bookName);
System.out.println("after: " + a.bookName);

//method in class C to get the data from the user via terminal

 public String getBookName(Scanner in, String bookName) 
 {

        System.out.println("enter name as appears in the database!");

        System.out.println("current value: >"+ bookName + "<");
        bookName = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("userInput: >" + bookName + "<");

        return bookName;
    }
```

the output (code in question has reduced user prompt than in image below):
[image]

when I run this code, the program runs through the `getBookName` method without stopping to get any user info. Why is the Scanner object not collecting the user input? and how do I modify the defect to collect a string with spaces (ex: "you are awesome for helping... Thanks!")?

I tried `in.reset()`, not initializing the global `bookName` variable, using `next()` instead of `nextLine()`, using `nextLine()` in a custom class to make sure I understand it, and a bunch of other stuff and I just don't get why this code doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code you haven't shown - it's obvious from your screenshot that there's user input before this part. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please show a *full* minimal example that I can run as-is to replicate the issue.

Comment: _A Scanner Oddly_

Comment: What? Not at 1 mil rep yet?

Comment: Dude you just got a reply from @JonSkeet you should seriously be honored right now

Comment: @Pshemo you are correct. The answer is found in that post. What is the etiquette now? do I delete the post?

Comment: I marked your question as duplicate. You don't have to delete it, you can leave it as sign pointing to main question about this problem. But feel free to improve your question just like Jon asked you.